how to update a user's document in firestore using Laravel
i have a users document i created and i would want to update user's email and amount
I'm using firestore and laravel, below is my controller
Thanks in advance
// my edit button below
<td><a href="{{ url('admin/edit-ref-transfer/'.$item['post_id']) }}" class="btn btn-dark">Debit</a></td>

//my route(web.php) code below
Route::get('edit-ref-transfer/{post_idz}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'edit']);
     Route::put('update-ref-transfer/{post_idz}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'update']);

//my edit form, retrieving the user's data here
<div class="iq-card-body">
<form action="{{ url('admin/update-ref-transfer/'.$key) }}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="cno">Referral point:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amountToPay" value="{{$addAmountToUserTotals[amount]}}" placeholder="Referral Point">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$addAmountToUserTotals[email]}}">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Debit</button>   
  </form>
  </div>

//below are my controllers DASHBORDCONTROLLER
public function edit($post_idz)
    {
    $key = $post_idz;
    $addAmountToUserTotals =  app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('refWithdrawlz')->document($key);
     if($addAmountToUserTotals)
        {
            return view('admin/edit-ref-transfer',compact('addAmountToUserTotals','key'));
        } else
        {
              return view('admin/ref-transfer')->with('status','error');
        }
    }


   public function update(Request $request, $post_idz)
    {
    $datetime = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
 $cur_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime)->format('d-m-Y');
  $addAmountToUserTotalszz =  app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('refWithdrawlz')->document($post_idz);
      $addAmountToUserTotalszz->update([
                  ['path' => 'amountToPay', 'value' => ((int)$request->amountToPay)],
                  ['path' => 'debitedAmount', 'value' => ((int)$request->amountToPay)],
                  ['path' => 'status', 'value' => ('Debited')],
                  ['path' => 'debitedDate', 'value' => ($cur_date)],
                ]);
                 if($addAmountToUserTotalszz)
        {
            return redirect('admin/ref-transfer')->with('status','Referral point debited successfully');
        } else
        {
              return redirect('admin/ref-transfer')->with('status','Referral point not successfully debited, please try again ');
        }
                
    }

please what am i getting wrong as i cant see the user's data on the form edit. i want to be able to edit users email and other fields and would like to retrieve them and update. i will be glad to get help thanks
